# Alinear a la derecha un texto en AdminLTE

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, adminlte

Necesito alinear un texto a la derecha en la plantilla AdminLTE, adjunto una imagen de lo que quiero hacer y despues el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es alinear esa fecha a la derecha, que el `select` y el botón se mantengan a la izquierda y la fecha a la derecha, los tres deben estar en la misma línea.

En el código los tres se encuentran dentro de un contenedor y cada uno en un bloque de contenido.

```css
.contenedor {
  margin: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.contenido {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="contenedor">
      <form method="POST" action="{% url 'cont_elect:Reporte2' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="contenido">
          {{ form.fecha }}
        </div>
        <div class="contenido">
          <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">
        </div>
        <div class="contenido">
          <h5>{{ i.fecha | date:"F, Y" }}</h5>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Agradeceria mucho la ayuda, ya que he intentado varias formas y no lo logro!

Comment: Mete los dos primeros en otro div, de manera que te queden dos bloques y al padre (actual clase `contenedor` le pones `display: flex;justify-content: space-between;`  ya te quedarán "empujados a los lados"

Comment: Bueno acabo de hacer lo que me dices y la verdad que no lo hace como necesito. Pero agradezco mucho su ayuda

Comment: Si quieres ayuda más detallada te recomiendo que nos proporciones un [mre], preferiblemente usando los snippets del sitio. El código que has puesto requiere que tengamos montado todo un servidor para poder probar... Crea un snippet que podamos modificar directamente y será más sencillo ayudarte. Además... deberías describir exactamente qué es lo que buscas, pues lo indicado en mi comentario genera exactamente lo que quieres, dejando el filtro a la izquierda y la fecha a la derecha.

Comment: Buenas, ya lo logré utilizando lo que me recomendaste, elproblema es que la clase row no me dejaba hacerlo, entonces la modifique. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes la opción de usar una clase adicional o id para el elemento que contiene la fecha y usar la propiedad `float: right;` que "empuja" este elemento a la derecha, justo como lo necesitas.

Adicionalmente, recomiendo no usar la etiqueta `<h5>` ya que tiene un `margin` que lo hace ver desalineado horizontalmente respecto a los demás elementos. Lo cambié por una etiqueta `<span>`, pero lo dejo a tu elección.

```css
.contenedor {
  margin: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.contenido {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.fecha {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="contenedor">
      <form method="POST" action="">
        <div class="contenido">
          <select>
            <option>Seleccione una fecha</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="contenido">
          <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">
        </div>
        <div class="contenido fecha">
          <span>Mayo, 2023</span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

También tienes la opción de usar `flexbox`, tal como te comentó @Benito-B y que, de acuerdo a tu comentario, te funcionó.

Comment: OK amigo, acabo de probarlo y me funciono perfectamente, claro tuve que sobreescribir la clase row, muchas gracias tambien para usted