# ¿Como poner ambas etiquetas en la misma linea?

Tags: html, css, datatables

necesito ayuda para mejorar la estetica de mi proyecto:

Les muestro la siguiente imagen de mi proyecto para que vean a lo que me refiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito poner el `boton de Excel` en la misma linea que esta el `select` y el `boton de filtrar`, o que el `select` y el `boton de filtrar` esten en la misma linea que el `boton de Excel`, cualquiera de las dos opciones es valida. Lo importante es que esten ambos en la misma linea y que el `select` y el `boton de filtrar` esten a la Isquierda y el `boton de Excel` a la Derecha.

El `boton de Excel` es generado utilizando la `clase="dt-button"` pues estoy trabajando con un datatable y estoy utilizando la plantilla AdminLTE-3.2.0.

Para lograr que el `select` y el `boton de filtrar` estuvieran en la misma linea utilice las siguientes propiedades de CSS:

```
  .contenedor {
            /*border: 1px solid black;*/
            /*padding: 2rem 2rem;*/
            /*margin: 1rem;*/  
            text-align: left;
        }
        .contenido {
            display: inline-block;
            /*border: 1px solid red;*/
            /*padding: 1rem 1rem;*/
            vertical-align: top;
        }
```

Comment: Tal vez [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/595067/alinear-a-la-derecha-un-texto-en-adminlte/595256#595256) te puede ayudar.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox), es una propiedad de CSS que te permite distribuir los elementos de una forma muy sencilla. Solamente tienes que darle al contenedor padre al propiedad `display:flex` y la propiedad `justify-content: space-between`, que para tu caso quedaría algo así:

```css
.parent-container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .parent-container select {
 width: 100%:
  }
  .parent-container button {
 margin-left: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <select>
    <option value="0">Seleccione el año...</option>
    <option value="2024">2024</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
  </select>
  <button>Botón 1</button>
  <button>Botón 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Esteban, convertí tu código en un snippet. Para el caso de HTML/CSS/Javascript es muy conveniente porque se puede ejecutar y ver el resultado en la respuesta misma. Te invito a [edit] la respuesta y ver su estructura. Fíjate en el enlace "editar este fragmento de código" y busca el botón para crear nuevos snippets mientras escribes la respuesta. Para que fuera funcional tuve que modificar un poco tu ejemlo de HTML. Un saludo.

Comment: Agradesco sus respuestas, pero creo que no me exprese bien con lo que necesito. Ya tengo mis clases .contenedor y .contenido las cuales se encuentran correctamente, el problema viene dado en la clase .dt-button la cual es la que muestra el boton de excel, esta clase dt-button aparece cuando se ejecuta el codigo JavaSript para exportar los datos del datatable, lo que quiero es que los 3 se encuentren en la misma linea